# How can i calculate 10 percent of a number entered in a text box and instantly show the result in another text box in php and html

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need help in solving this problem. I have a text box that collects a figure. Now i can calculate 10% of that value and then add the result to the initial value from the textbox to get a final value with the 10% included. What i need help for is how do i display that final value in another text box without submitting and form. That is, as the value is entered in the first textbox, automatically the percentage is calculated and added to initial figure and the result outputted in the second textbox.

the code to calculate the percentage is below:

```
<?php
$percentage = 10;
$percentindecimal = $percentage / 100;
$amountdue = ($percentindecimal * $amountneeded) + $amountneeded; 
?>

<form>
  <input name="amountneeded" type="text">
  <output name="amountdue" type="text"></output>
</form>
```

Comment: You're going to have to do it in JavaScript if you don't want a form submit.

Comment: @jmoerdyk That's the problem. I am not good in javascript.

Comment: So start by adding event listeners.... Than read the value.... than do calculation, than update the value of an element

Comment: Sorry to be blunt, but "I'm not good at javascript" is not a reason to get us to write **all** your javascript for you. What you need would be covered in pretty basic javascript tutorials. Making some attempt at writing the javascript yourself will result in less down votes.

Comment: @Jon P you did not need to down vote the question. This platform is supposed to help get people to look at a problem together and proffer solution based on individual knowledge.I don't know javascript and that's why i asked here because i believed it would require a JavaScript solution. Unless there was some way in php to do this.

Comment: I disagree. This platform is meant for us to help each other and share our collective knowledge. However, it is **not** a code writing service. You have effectively given us a specification and asked us to write your code for you. It is a shortened version of "Here is an application in C#, please write it in Python for me". If you had written some javascript and asked a question about the specific trouble you with that, your question would be much better recieved.

Comment: @JonP I think you need to read the first line of what you just said. "This platform is meant for us to help each other and share our collective knowledge." Someone else who even has a higher reputation than you did not make any noise. Instead he helped. And going through what he did, i have learnt some new things today. That is what this platform is for. Like you stated in the first line of what you said.

Comment: @AgbogidiMichael be that as it may, what has been said is true, this requires JavaScript and regardless of your skill level with it, you need to employ it. So learn JavaScript.

Comment: What you may have missed is that I'm attempting to help you as well, just in a different way. I'm trying to help you understand what makes a good StackOverflow question that will hopefully get you reputation, not lose it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your form to communicate with your PHP script without being submitted, you'd need to make use of JavaScript to `POST` the information to the PHP script with [**AJAX**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)). While you **could** use AJAX for this, considering your PHP script is fairly small (and you'd need JavaScript anyway), it would make more sense to simply do the calculation in JavaScript itself (cutting out PHP entirely).

To do this, I would recommend calling a function [**`onblur`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onblur) that passes through the `value` of the `<input>` with the [**`this`** keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). You would then make the calculation inside this function, and then outputting the results to the second element with **[`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)**. Considering you have no IDs or classes, the easiest way to target the desired output element is with **[`.getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName)**:

```js
function calculate(input) {
  input = parseInt(input); // State that the input received is a number
  // Without the parsing, the addition would be *appended* to the input value
  input += input / 10; // Add 10% of input to itself
  document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML = input; // Output the result
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="amountneeded" type="text" onblur="calculate(this.value)">
  <span name="amountdue" type="text"></span>
</form>
```

Note that `<output>` is not a valid HTML element, so I've substituted this for `<span>`.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: This is a good answer to a particularly poor question. I would probably not assume an `int` as input though. It could be float/decimal

Comment: @Obsidian Age Just a quick one. With an ID i could do something like this right? `document.getElementById('amountdue')[0].innerHTML = input`;

Comment: Something **like** that yes; you'd simply need to remove the `[0]`, going with `document.getElementById('amountdue').innerHTML = input`. I used it in my snippet because `.getElementsByClassName` returns a NodeList collection, rather than a single element. `[0]` denotes that you want 'the first one' from that group, though there's only one result from `.getElementByID`, so you don't need to state that you're grabbing the first one in that 'set' ;)

Comment: @Obsidian Age Thanks a lot. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @ObsidianAge Changed the `onBlur` to `onKeyUp` Like it better that way. You see the result as you enter the digits.

Comment: ^ Sure, that sounds better to me :)